# How to maintain object reference when serializing

Tags: c#, serialization

Okay, I'm a little fuzzy on how this works or if it's possible.  I want to serialize the Child class, but I don't actually want to serialize a Parent object when it does the Child.MyParent field... I just want the reference to be serialized.  Is this possible and how would I go about it?

```
public class Parent
{ 
    public Child New()
    {
        return new Child(this);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public Parent MyParent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        MyParent = parent;
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm using DataContractSerializer, but I'm not opposed to switching to something else if necessary.

Comment: Child can mark MyParent is as transient; that keeps it from being serialized, but you 'just want the reference to be serialized'.  Could you explain exactly what you're wanting?  When an object is serialized and deserialized references don't really have meaning.

Comment: @seand I'm trying to leverage serialization to let me clone some objects.  Basically they will be serialized and then immediately deserialized.  I recognize there is an ICloneable interface for this, but I think this will let me do it on a range of different types without having to implement that interface on all of them.

Comment: I am thinking that it may be better to just not serialize this field and manage it outside of the serialization process, but if it's possible I'd like to know how.

Comment: Which serialization method are you using?

Comment: @Brandon if there's a 'dumb data' representation of Parent (such as an id integer or simple string) you could just serialize that instead.  But I'm also wondering why you really want to serialize and immediately deserializing.  It sounds like a clunky way to impl clone.

Comment: @M.Babcock I'm using DataContractSerializer.  I just found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473182/maintain-object-references-through-serialize-deserialize) that says to set PreserveObjectReferences to true, but it's a read only property as far as I can tell so I don't see how to do that.

Comment: Although it looks like PreserveObjectReferences might not be quite what I'm looking for either...

Comment: @kamalnayan I saw that and thought it might help until I realized that it's just preserving a reference to a single serialized version of an object... not actually preserving a 'pointer' to an object in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [XMLIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) can be applied to fields that you don's want serialized. For example,

```
public class Child
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Parent MyParent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        MyParent = parent;
    }
}
```

But as far as serializing a reference to the field, you'd have to provide more info on how you plan to persist the object that the reference points to. What is your reason to not just serialize the `Parent` member (in your case)? It's common to serialize all the public members that are needed.

If you just want to use serialization to clone, something like this should work:

```
private static Parent Clone(Parent parent)
{
    Parent parentClone = null;
    lock (m_lock) // serialize cloning.
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, parent);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            parentClone = (Parent)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    return parentClone;
}
```

Comment: I'm just trying to leverage serialization to clone an object.  So an object is serialized into a byte[] variable and then immediately deserialized into a new object.  The parent object is never serialized.  I'm thinking a better approach may be to find a way to just re-set the Parent property after the serialization process though.

Comment: @BrandonMoore - You might be able to use [IDeserializationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx) to do this.

Comment: Oh, btw I'm trying to clone the child and not the parent... looks like your example is doing the other way around.  In any case I agree the IDeserializationCallback is prolly going to be the only sane way to handle this.

Comment: Of course... not that it matters whether this example shows the parent being cloned since the logic works equally either way :)

Comment: Well if it's an immediate re-serialization couldn't you just set the XmlIgnore property, then when you deserialize it the Parent object should be _null_ and you can set the Parent property to the Parent of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to implement your own serialization and deserialization functionality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata.aspx

Here's an extract from MSDN

```
[Serializable]
    public class Person : ISerializable
    {
        private string name_value;
        private int ID_value;

        public Person() { }
        protected Person(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            if (info == null)
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
            name_value = (string)info.GetValue("AltName", typeof(string));
            ID_value = (int)info.GetValue("AltID", typeof(int));
        }

        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand,Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
        public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            if (info == null)
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
            info.AddValue("AltName", "XXX");
            info.AddValue("AltID", 9999);
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name_value; }
            set { name_value = value; }
        }

        public int IdNumber
        {
            get { return ID_value; }
            set { ID_value = value; }
        }
    }
```