# How To Serialize A .net Class To Disk

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to serialize an object cache to disk so it can be loaded the next time the program is loaded.
One of the features of the class being saved is it contains references to other objects.
For example:
I have a list of an image class that stores remote url, local filepath, if it's been downloaded etc.... I then bind visibility to downloaded and the source to the local filepath.
Other Objects have a reference to this image so when the image is downloaded it's updated once and all the bindings update across all items that are pointing at it.

As a quick fix I implemented a binary formatter and all is working correctly.  All my lists are serialized to disk and when I reload them all the references remain (I.E 1 image object is created and everything that uses it has a reference as opposed to deserialisation creating a new instance of Image everytime it appears)

My question is what kind of Serialier I should be using to store to disk whilst not breaking my references?  I've read that BinaryFormatter is a BAD choice for serializing to disk and expecting it to work across different releases. Although I've had no issues with it so far I don't want to run into problems a year down the road and force all my users so re-aquire all their cached metadata.

I'm not 100% sure how all the different serializers work but I presume I may need to write some kind of convertor if I were to use XML.  If it helps, all of my image objects have a GUID assigned to them so I have something unique about every object.

UPDATE: I've just found the following question which looks similar [Maintain object references through Serialize/Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473182/maintain-object-references-through-serialize-deserialize)
Can anyone tell me if Datacontractserializer is a good choice for long term serialization storage across different versions of an applciation Vs the downsides of binaryformatter?

Comment: Take a look at [Redis persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence)

Comment: @oleksii you realise that is completely unrelated to object serialization, right?

Comment: @MarcGravell no sorry, I don't realise this. I made a comment because (I am sure you know better than me) redis is a distributed cache provider and it has a built-in functionality of persisting data into the drive. If this functionality is already implemented in the industry solution, why reinvent the wheel? And I didn't make it as an answer because I do realise it may not be simple (or desired) to bring a new dependency on redis. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would suggest treating your cache as a temporary store only.  If you want to reload it from disk - then it must still be valid.  You need to add a way to invalidate the cache data (time, version, etc) if its expired.  Where is the cache data originating from?  If you are trying to load both from the original source (db) and the cache -then you would have two separate objects unless you have a custom method to "match" them up in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for any converters and stuff, just check this out:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Comment: The article states "One thing to remember is that the basic XML serialization won't maintain references." "Now I have a list containing two of the exact same movie reference. When I serialize and deserialize this list, it will be converted to two separate instances of the movie object - they would just have the same information. Along this same line, the XMLSerializer also doesn't support circular references. If you need this kind of flexibility, you should consider binary serialization." So this doesn't seem to fill the requirement.

Comment: Ah, missed that part.. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Well, you're article has helped me in what to search for and I think I've found the answer so still useful.

Comment: Good! Glad I could help, in one way or the other ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**MongoDb** may be useful. See [MongoDB for C#](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center)
or other type of DataBase: **[DB4Object](http://www.db4o.com/s/csharpdb.aspx)**

and seems be SQLite useful. use blobs for store images as binary.

Comment: Do you know what kind of performance I'd get from this Vs sql ce - I was using sql ce but was far to slow for my requirement which is why I had to find another solution to the problem.

Comment: You can see more solutions like [db4object](http://www.db4o.com/s/csharpdb.aspx). but it seems SQLite have a good performance for your issue.

Answer (score -1):

[SqLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) may help in it, its easy to use.

Comment: How?  Please provide some more details to your answer.